# SQL group by 3 second rolling timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, azure-sql-database, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to group some data in SQL (Azure specifically) by a rolling 3 second timestamp.

For example, from the table below (**EXISTING TABLE EXAMPLE**), I am wanting to say
Does the timestamp in "PERFORMED_AT" for "TICKET_ROW_NUMBER" 2 happen within 3 seconds of the timestamp in "PEFRORMED_AT" for "TICKET_ROW_NUMBER" 1... If so, then assign "GROUP_NUMBER"

Where this gets tricky, is I want this to then check row 3, but if row 3 "PERFORMED_AT" is within 3 seconds of row 2, I want it assigned to the same group number. Then, if a timestamp is outside the 3 second window, then start a new group number.

So I would want my end table to look like (**DESIRED TABLE EXAMPLE**)

Also, this table is actually hundreds of thousands of rows, with tens of thousands of tickets, not just this one example.

**EXISTING TABLE EXAMPLE**

| TICKET_ID | TICKET_ROW_NUMBER | ACTIVITY_ID | PERFORMED_AT | PREVIOUS_PERFORMED | GROUP_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 375034 | 1 | 16666494280232 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 2 | 16666494282815 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 3 | 16666494514274 | 2022-10-24 22:10:51.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 4 | 16666494540000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:54.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:51.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 5 | 16666516150000 | 2022-10-24 22:46:55.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:54.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 6 | 16666516166334 | 2022-10-30 22:46:27.000 | 2022-10-24 22:46:55.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 7 | 16671699897226 | 2022-10-30 22:46:29.000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:27.000 | NULL |
| 375034 | 8 | 16671699910000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:31.000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:29.000 | NULL |

**DESIRED TABLE EXAMPLE**

| TICKET_ID | TICKET_ROW_NUMBER | ACTIVITY_ID | PERFORMED_AT | PREVIOUS_PERFORMED | GROUP_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 375034 | 1 | 16666494280232 | 10/24/2022 22:10:28 | 10/24/2022 22:10:28 | 1 |
| 375034 | 2 | 16666494282815 | 10/24/2022 22:10:28 | 10/24/2022 22:10:28 | 1 |
| 375034 | 3 | 16666494514274 | 10/24/2022 22:10:51 | 10/24/2022 22:10:28 | 2 |
| 375034 | 4 | 16666494540000 | 10/24/2022 22:10:54 | 10/24/2022 22:10:51 | 2 |
| 375034 | 5 | 16666516150000 | 10/24/2022 22:46:55 | 10/24/2022 22:10:54 | 3 |
| 375034 | 6 | 16666516166334 | 10/30/2022 22:46:27 | 10/24/2022 22:46:55 | 4 |
| 375034 | 7 | 16671699897226 | 10/30/2022 22:46:29 | 10/30/2022 22:46:27 | 4 |
| 375034 | 8 | 16671699910000 | 10/30/2022 22:46:31 | 10/30/2022 22:46:29 | 4 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return the list of each partition suspicious transactions from each sender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312208/how-can-i-return-the-list-of-each-partition-suspicious-transactions-from-each-se)

Comment: This is a classic gaps and islands problem, search for that term and you shall find answers

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference between the `PERFORMED_AT` and `PREVIOUS_PERFORMED` values , you can use the `DATEDIFF` function, and then to assign a `GROUP_NUMBER` to each row, you can use `SUM` function and calculate the running total.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    TICKET_ID, 
    TICKET_ROW_NUMBER, 
    ACTIVITY_ID, 
  PERFORMED_AT,
    PREVIOUS_PERFORMED,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, PREVIOUS_PERFORMED, PERFORMED_AT) AS DIFFERENCE
  FROM 
    TicketActivity
)
SELECT 
  TICKET_ID, 
  TICKET_ROW_NUMBER, 
  ACTIVITY_ID, 
  PERFORMED_AT, 
  PREVIOUS_PERFORMED, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE <= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TICKET_ID ORDER BY TICKET_ROW_NUMBER)+1 AS GROUP_NUMBER
FROM 
  cte;
```

Here `CASE` statement is used to determine whether to include each row in the running total.

**Output:**

| TICKET_ID | TICKET_ROW_NUMBER | ACTIVITY_ID | PERFORMED_AT | PREVIOUS_PERFORMED | GROUP_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 375034 | 1 | 16666494280232 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 1 |
| 375034 | 2 | 16666494282815 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 1 |
| 375034 | 3 | 16666494514274 | 2022-10-24 22:10:51.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:28.000 | 2 |
| 375034 | 4 | 16666494540000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:54.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:51.000 | 2 |
| 375034 | 5 | 16666516150000 | 2022-10-24 22:46:55.000 | 2022-10-24 22:10:54.000 | 3 |
| 375034 | 6 | 16666516166334 | 2022-10-30 22:46:27.000 | 2022-10-24 22:46:55.000 | 4 |
| 375034 | 7 | 16671699897226 | 2022-10-30 22:46:29.000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:27.000 | 4 |
| 375034 | 8 | 16671699910000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:31.000 | 2022-10-30 22:46:29.000 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T3T-ac8z)